# TypeError: p is undefined when using xtype: 'treepicker'. Extjs6

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the record editing window, I need to use the tree selector, for this, the file `Ext.ux.TreePicker` is included in the `app.js` file, which is located in the `app` folder on the same level as the `app.js` file.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'app');
Ext.application({
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    name: 'App',    
    appFolder: 'app',
    requires: ['Ext.ux.TreePicker'], 
...
```

In the record editing window, set the `xtype: 'treepicker'` field:

```
Ext.define('App.view.OperationEdit', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'operation-edit',
    alias: 'widget.operationedit',    
    controller: 'operation_controller',  
    viewModel: {
        type: 'operation_model'
    },                  
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        margin: 10,
        labelAlign: 'top'
    },    
    closable: true,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',      
            items: [
{           
    xtype: 'treepicker',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.get('StorageStore'),
    fieldLabel: "Mesto_hraneniya",
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'text',
    selectChildren: true,
    canSelectFolders: true,
    name: 'mesto_hraneniya'    
 },
......
```

When I open the edit window, I get an error:

```
TypeError: p is undefined
```

Example link [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2sp6)

Why does an error appear? How to display the treepicker field correctly?

thank

Comment: Why not share a fiddle in fiddle.sencha.com, so that it would be easier to help ?

Comment: @ abeyaz  I added a link to the example to the question, but for some reason the TreePicker.js file does not want to connect. In a local application, a file connection occurs.

Comment: you must check "ux" checkbox at the bottom of the packages list to make it work.

Comment: @abeyaz When I check the box Ux and open the record for editing, an error appears:`TypeError: item is undefined` . Treepicker is located in the app/view/ TestEdit.js  editing window. This window opens when adding or editing a record

Comment: check my answer, i made it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code, at least in your fiddle is that you defined the "edit form" as fully json, which will be parsed and executed on load time. Since, there is no StorageStore at load time, store parameter of treepicker will be null and that is the reason you get an error. Proper way would be to set form items on object instantiaton as follows, and the working fiddle is [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2sp7).

```
Ext.define('App.view.TestEdit', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'test-edit',
    alias: 'widget.testedit',
    requires: ['App.store.StorageStore'],
    controller: 'app_view_testgrid',
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        margin: 10,
        labelAlign: 'top'
    },
    closable: true,
    items: [],

    initConfig: function(config){
        config = config || {};
        config.items = [
            {
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: {
                    type: 'type-store'
                },
                fieldLabel: 'Type',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',
                name: 'id_type',
                reference: 'mycombo',

            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'My field',
                name: 'mytextfield'
            }, {
                xtype: 'treepicker',
                store: Ext.data.StoreManager.get("StorageStore"),
                fieldLabel: "Mesto_hraneniya",
                valueField: 'id',
                displayField: 'text',
                selectChildren: true,
                canSelectFolders: true,
                name: 'mesto_hraneniya'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                minWidth: 70,
                text: 'Save',
                listeners: {
                    click: 'saveRecord'
                }
            }]
        }    
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible in ViewController, before opening the window to load the store StorageStore by establishing a connection using 'reference:'? As made for combobox

Comment: Thank you very much. Only one clarification, why the established value of the 'mesto_hraneniya' field is not displayed in an open form?

Comment: Because you didnt use "id" in the record. You can set value of a combo or picker field by using `valueField`, in this case `id`. Check how you did it for type field, you should follow the same method.

Comment: Thank you. I added 'name: 'mesto_hraneniya_id'' and added value 'mesto_hraneniya_id' in json data. Its work